# How properly connect libcurl to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, curl

I want to use in my project libcurl library. So here are steps that I did to connect libcurl library to MSVS 2012:
1. I downloaded this package from official site [libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip)
2. All dll and lib files I placed in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib
3. curl folder with header files i copied to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include
4. In VS 2012 in Project's options i added curllib.lib string
5. dll files I also copied to Project's Debug folder

But when I run this example:

```
int main(void)
{
CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.copy.com/oauth/request");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
return 0
}
```

I get an error that there is missing libsasl.dll. What is libsasl.dll and where i should get it if there is no such file in package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a lot of different versions of libsasl.dll but they all were outdated. But on this [forum](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/282532-libcurl-and-libsasldll-dependency-using-make-files-on-windows/) I found advice to download [OpenLDAP for Windows](http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx) and use libsasl.dll from program folder. And that works!

Comment: I duplicated your success by running the program, using https, on Visual Studio 2013. However, trying to get libcurl to run on Visual Studio is a lousy experience. Yeah, libcurl may compile everywhere but you can't build and run it on Visual Studio. Another example of a broken open source project -- ok, maybe only in Visual Studio.